# Why can't I save battle videos in Moon vs my friend's Ultra Moon?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

I can save battles against other people, but not my friend. They joined the game not too long ago. I have Pokemon Moon and he has Pokemon Ultra Moon. I couldn't save any of the battles that we had, but he *could* save the battles.

Is there a way I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Pokemon Sun and Moon games cannot save Battle Videos when pitted against Pokemon Ultra Sun and Ultra Moon games. Either use an Ultra Sun or Ultra Moon game, or have your friend use a Sun or Moon game.